# Strict aliasing exceptions explanations

Tags: c++, inheritance, reinterpret-cast, strict-aliasing

First two exceptions of strict aliasing rule on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing) says:

> - AliasedType is (possibly cv-qualified) DynamicType
> - AliasedType and DynamicType are both (possibly multi-level, possibly cv-qualified at each level) pointers to the same type T (since C++11)

I don't clearly understand the difference between these cases.
For instance:

```
struct B { virtual ~B() {} };
struct D : B {};

B* b = new D;
reinterpret_cast<D*>(b);
```

Is the code above suitable for both cases or not?

As far as I see `AliasedType` and `DynamicType` both are `D` (1st case) and they are pointers to same type `D`.

If I’m wrong could you provide examples for each separate case and explain the difference more clearly?

Comment: cppreference is wrong here. You cannot `reinterpret_cast` a base pointer to a derived pointer or back, and then dereference the converted pointer, regardless of the dynamic type of the object.

Comment: @n.m. could you provide any reference to the standard?

Comment: 6.9.2p4. "Two objects a and b are pointer-interconvertible if ..." Only the first base class subobject is allowed and only if the object has standard layout.

Comment: Why use `reinterpret_cast` when `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` (run time checked) would work?

Comment: @BoPersson my interest is mostly on theoretic part here. In production code I would prefer more obvious cast.

Comment: @n.m. [several answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AliasedType+is+%28possibly+cv-qualified%29+DynamicType+is%3Aa) (mostly from Jonathan Mee) refer to that cppreference page. Maybe they should be reviewed?

Comment: @n.m. what about 6.10p8? Looks like that paragraph is an source for cppreference page.

Comment: The [talk page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Talk:cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) basically says the main page is wrong and needs to be reviewed, so yeah.

Comment: 6.10p8 doesn't give you a license to reinterpret_cast anything. It says you can access an object through its dynamic pointer type *or* through a pointer to one of its base classes. It doesn't say they have to be convertible one to another with a reinterpret_cast (and it could not have possibly say that because it is night impossible to implement inheritance and reinterpret cast this way, or at least no existing implementation implements them this way).

Answer (score 2):

To understand the statement there, you have to realize that `DynamicType` refers to the type of the **object**, and `AliasedType` to the type of the expression used to access that value. But the cast itself is not from `DynamicType` to `AliasedType`, but from `DynamicType*` to `AliasedType*`.

Now, C++ has multi-level pointers. `DynamicType` can be some `A*` and `AliasedType` can be some `B*`, possibly cv-qualified. Hence, `DynamicType*` would be `A**`. This is why you need the second case. `AliasedType` could be a `A const*`, which is different from `A*`. Hence, it's not covered under the first rule (`A const*` is **not** a cv-qualified version of `A*`, unlike `A* const`).

Now, as for your code: The `DynamicType` of your object is `D`, which is very obvious from `new D`. `D` is **not** a pointer type, it's a class type. This means only cv-qualifed variants can alias it: `volatile D`, `const D`, and `const volatile D`.

However, you don't have a pointer to that `D` object, you have a pointer to its `B` sub-object. This sub-object can be aliased by a `B const` etc.

What you are doing is trying to gain access the `B` sub-object using an `AliasedType` of `D`. That isn't going to work - `D` is not a cv-qualified `B`. They're related by inheritance, not cv-qualification.

Comment: Reference is also allowed. But what about *real* examples for these two cases? Does my code completely wrong as @n.m. said?

Comment: @alexolut: Yes.

Comment: Could you add correct code snippets to your answer for both mentioned cases? I think answer will be completed in that situation and I could accept it.